# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword not working in vue.js

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to get the sign in part working on my webapp but it's not working properly.
Whenever I press the login button the page either refreshes and the url gets updated with the credentials and stays at the same page OR the router gets pushed and goes to the 'homepage' without logging the user in.

I also followed this guide for reference: https://blog.logrocket.com/vue-firebase-authentication/

What's weird is that the sign up part is working just fine.

**SignIn.vue**

```
<div class="card-body">
          <form>
            <!-- email -->
            <div class="input-group form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" value required autofocus v-model="form.email" />
            </div>
            <!-- password -->
            <div class="input-group form-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password" required v-model="form.password" />
            </div>
            <!-- error -->
            <div v-if="error" class="alert alert-danger animated shake">{{ error }}</div>
            <br />

            <!-- login -->
            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div class="row align-items-center remember"><input type="checkbox" v-model="form.rememberMe" />Remember Me</div>
              <input type="submit" @click="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

**Script in SignIn.vue**

```
<script>
  import firebase from 'firebase';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          rememberMe: false
        },
        error: null
      };
    },
    methods: {
      submit() {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.email, this.form.password)
          .catch(err => {
            this.error = err.message;
          })
          .then(data => {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
          });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import profile from './modules/profile';
import authenticate from './modules/authenticate';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    profile,
    authenticate
  }
});
```

**Authenticate.js in store**

```
const state = {
  user: {
    loggedIn: false,
    data: null
  }
};

const getters = {
  user(state) {
    return state.user;
  }
};

const mutations = {
  SET_LOGGED_IN(state, value) {
    state.user.loggedIn = value;
  },
  SET_USER(state, data) {
    state.user.data = data;
  }
};

const actions = {
  fetchUser({ commit }, user) {
    commit('SET_LOGGED_IN', user !== null);
    if (user) {
      commit('SET_USER', {
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email
      });
    } else {
      commit('SET_USER', null);
    }
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you assign the `submit` type to your button, your form is submitted before the Firebase method is triggered.

You should change the button code from

```
 <input type="submit" @click="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" />
```

to

```
 <input type="button" @click="submit" value="Login" class="btn float-right login_btn" />
```

---

See the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) for more detail on button types.

Comment: This worked well. However when implementing this I couldn't login with the Enter key anymore. To fix this I had to implement the `@submit.prevent` in the form. Doing so I was able to keep the `type="submit"` in the button.